# Mostrar texto na página apartir do banco de dados em django

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django, fetch

Olá,
Estou tentando exibir um texto apartir do banco de dados em mysql, utilizando Django, já procurei por vários tutoriais mas nada funciona, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço desde já.

Este é parte do meu arquivo: **index.html**

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
  <div class="small-box bg-warning">
    <div class="inner">
      {% for rf in indrf %}
      <h3>{{rf.id}}</h3>
      {% endfor %}
      <p>Indicações registradas</p>
    </div>
```

Este é meu aquivo de modelo: **models.py**

```python
from django.db import models

class indications(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    obs = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Este é parte do aquivo view: **views.py**

```
def countrefused(request):
    indrf = indications.objects.all()
    return render(request,"index.html",{'indrf':indrf})
```

Porem toda vez que executo, o código não me retorna nada.
Grato!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
        return f'{name} {phone} {obs} {status}'
```

`__str__` é um função usada  para retornar uma representação de string de um objeto na classe indications
**(** Nome de classe sempre com letra maiúscula para diferenciar de objetos e funções **Indications** deveria ser **)**

aplicando no código da classe Indications

```
from django.db import models

class indications(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    obs = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   # user_id = models.CharField(max_length=50) django seta como auto incremeto o ids
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{name} {phone} {obs} {status}'
```

esta recuperando nome phone obs e status. pode indicar quais irão ser retornadas não necessariamente pode ser todas.

na página html sera passado os nomes como:

```
{% for rf in indrf %}
      <h3>{{rf.id}} {{rf.name}} {{rf.phone}}</h3>
      {% endfor %}
      <p>Indicações registradas</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado por sua ajuda, funcionou corretamente.